# When does the Rubin Causal Model fail in practice?

Tags: causality

The Rubin Causal Model frames the causal inference question as the problem of inferring missing potential outcomes (what the outcome would have been if a unit had received a different treatment) in order to estimate the causal effects of hypothetical treatments/interventions.

It seems like an intuitive and very general framework. When is this approach most likely to fail in practice? Why isn't it more widely used?

Comment: What do you mean by fail?